# Prevent IP forwarding with firewalld

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld

I may have misunderstood something here, but I expected to be able to block packet forwarding using `firewalld`, but it seems to only deal with the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains, not the `FORWARD` chain. Is there a simple way to get `firewalld` to prevent forwarding (or am I relegated to using direct `iptables` rules)?

Simple case:

```
Host MAIN
   Connects to PUBLIC
   Connects to NET_A (1.1.1.0/24)
   Connects to NET_B (2.2.2.0/24)
```

I want forwarding to be allowed from NET_B to NET_A, but not from PUBLIC to NET_A. ie. something logically equivalent to:

```
source=2.2.2.0/24 dest=1.1.1.0/24 ALLOW
source=0.0.0.0/0 dest=1.1.1.0/24 REJECT
```

While I can define rules like the above using `fiewwalld` zones, the resulting `iptables` entries do not apply to the `FORWARD` tables, so all packets just forward normally.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This might be useful (but I don't use firewalld myself): https://firewalld.org/2020/04/intra-zone-forwarding . Probably requires configuring interfaces / zone mappings and probably a recent version.

Comment: That seems to be about allowing even more forwarding. I'm trying to restrict it.

Comment: The reject rule, can be placed right at the bottom of the chain. The last rule must reject any source to any destination (implicit deny)

Comment: I think you are missing the problem: firewalld rules (execpt when using port forwarding) seem to ONLY touch the INPUT and OUTPUT tables. This means that in the above example there is no way to get the host to block packets going from 1.1.1.x to 2.2.2.y. ie. firewalld does not affect the FORWARD table, even if the source/dest are non-local.

Comment: Note: I did not edit in time. In the above, change '1.1.1.x to 2.2.2.y' to '0.0.0.0/0 to 1.1.1.0/24'.